# Delphi IOHandler Read Unknown Number of Bytes

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi XE5, having worked mainly with VB.Net and some Java.  I am trying to read an unknown number of bytes from an incoming TCP connection and am not having any luck researching how to determine how many bytes are in the input buffer to read. It seems that every method I try, i.e. ReadBytes, ReadStream, etc. require that I explicitly tell them how many bytes to read or they block. I just need a way to determine how many bytes are in the input buffer so I can use ReadBytes for example to read them.

```
begin
  Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(300);
  if Not Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    Client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(rxBuf);
end;
```

In order for this not to block I need to supply the number of bytes in the input buffer, but I cannot determine how to do that.  I tried InputBuffer.Size, but that returned a much larger number than could possibly be there.

I have now tried the following:

```
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    if Not Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
    end;
  end
  else
    Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
end;
```

When I put a breakpoint and step through the code, the code skips over ExtractToBytes and rxBuf remains nil even though there is data in the input buffer. Why?

I left out some of the code before.  Here is the whole thing.

```
while stop-start <MainForm.Timeout do
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    stop := Ticks;
    if Not Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
      break;
    end;
  end
  else
    Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
  break;
end;
```

I know there is data in the buffer because stepping through the code goes to the break; but the ExtractToBytes(rxBuf) is not evaluated and a do not know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InputBuffer.Size` is the actual number of bytes physically in the `InputBuffer` memory.  It cannot be larger than what is actually stored.  `InputBufferIsEmpty()` simply returns whether `InputBuffer.Size > 0` or not.

```
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  Client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(rxBuf, Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
end;
```

Or, use `InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes()` unconditionally to extract whatever is currently in the `InputBuffer`, even if it happens to be empty:

```
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can pass `-1` to `ReadBytes()`, which tells it to return whatever is currently in the `InputBuffer` (it will first call `IOHandler.ReadFromSource()` to fill the `InputBuffer` before then extracting from it):

```
begin
  Client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(rxBuf, -1, False);
end;
```

**Update:** Your loop is calling `break` regardless of whether anything is read. Is that what you really want? If not, then you need to move the last `break` into a `begin/end` block so that it is only evaluated if `ExtractToBytes()` is called:

```
while GetTickDiff(start, Ticks) < MainForm.Timeout do
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
    if Not Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
      break;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
    break;
  end;
end;
```

In which case, you can then simplify the loop a bit:

```
start := Ticks;
while Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty do
begin
  if GetTickDiff(start, Ticks) >= MainForm.Timeout then Break;
  Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
end;
Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
```

In which case, you could just get rid of the loop altogether and just utilize Indy's own timeouts instead:

```
Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(MainForm.Timeout);
Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
```

Or:

```
Client.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := MainForm.Timeout;
Client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(rxBuf, -1, False);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. What I do not understand is why if there is data in the input buffer that ExtractBytes would not be evaluated? Here is the logic I am trying to implement. I am communicating over TCP with a serial device. I send it a character which opens communication and it responds with some information that can vary in size.

```
// Stay in loop until a certain amount of time has passed with no data
// I understand I can use the timeout as well
while GetTickDiff(start, Ticks) < MainForm.Timeout do
  begin
    if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      begin
        Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
        if Not Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
          begin
            // If there is data in the buffer get it
            // But why is ExtractToBytes not evaluated
            Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
            // I break the loop because I am assuming ExtractToBytes has been evaluated
            break;
          end;
      end
    else
      begin
      Client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(rxBuf);
      break;
  end;
```

end;

What I am apparently misunderstanding is that just because there is data in the input buffer, ExtractToBytes will not necessarily be evaluated.  Thanks for your input, I will play around with it some more.